# split cell to rows by pipe python

Tags: python

I am trying to split a cell into 2 rows by pipe ("|").

For instance:

```
ID  Site    Category    Queries

1   0        38037      antique+wall+telephone|antique+wall+phone
```

will become:

```
ID  Site    Category    Queries

1   0         38037     antique+wall+telephone

1   0         38037     antique+wall+phone
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
>>> id, site, category, queries
('1', '0', '38037', 'antique+wall+telephone|antique+wall+phone')
>>> for query in queries.split('|'):
...     print id, site, category, query
... 
1 0 38037 antique+wall+telephone
1 0 38037 antique+wall+phone
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .split()

```
input = "antique+wall+telephone|antique+wall+phone"
output = input.split('|')
```

output will be a list of elements either side of the '|'

so output would be

```
("antique+wall+telephone", "antique+wall+phone")
```

and then you can simply add the ID Number in front of each element of the list of strings

Hope that answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Using talend, You can also use tNormalize component : you just have to specify the column to normalize in the dropdown menu. Be careful if you want to use "|" as the item separator, as it is a reserved character, you have to escape it using "\|".
[image]